# Ошибка yum: Error unpacking rpm package

Tags: linux, centos, yum

Пробую обновить пакеты на одном из серверов Centos7, получаю ошибку при установке.

```
[user@server123 ~]$ sudo yum update
Загружены модули: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.wiuwiu.de
* epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
* extras: mirror.23media.de
* updates: mirror.netcologne.de
Разрешение зависимостей
--> Проверка сценария
---> Пакет grub2-common.noarch 1:2.02-0.64.el7.centos помечен для обновления
---> Пакет grub2-common.noarch 1:2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2 помечен как обновление
---> Пакет grub2-efi-x64.x86_64 1:2.02-0.64.el7.centos помечен для обновления
---> Пакет grub2-efi-x64.x86_64 1:2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2 помечен как обновление
---> Пакет kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.5.2.el7 помечен для установки
--> Проверка зависимостей окончена

Зависимости определены

================================================================================
Package           Архитектура
                              Версия                          Репозиторий
                                                                          Размер
================================================================================
Установка:
kernel            x86_64     3.10.0-693.5.2.el7              updates      43 M
Обновление:
grub2-common      noarch     1:2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2        updates     726 k
grub2-efi-x64     x86_64     1:2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2        updates     1.1 M

Итого за операцию
================================================================================
Установить  1 пакет
Обновить    2 пакета

Объем загрузки: 45 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
(1/3): grub2-common-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.noarch.rpm      | 726 kB   00:00
(2/3): grub2-efi-x64-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.x86_64.rpm     | 1.1 MB   00:00
(3/3): kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.rpm                |  43 MB   00:01
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Общий размер                                        23 MB/s |  45 MB  00:01
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Обновление  : 1:grub2-common-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.noarch                1/5
Error unpacking rpm package 1:grub2-common-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: lstat
  Обновление  : 1:grub2-efi-x64-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.x86_64               2/5
Error unpacking rpm package 1:grub2-efi-x64-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.x86_64
error: grub2-common-1:2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.noarch: install failed
error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: lstat
  Установка   : kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64                            3/5
Error unpacking rpm package kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
error: grub2-efi-x64-1:2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.x86_64: install failed
error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: lstat
1:grub2-efi-x64-2.02-0.64.el7.centos.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Проверка    : 1:grub2-efi-x64-2.02-0.64.el7.centos.x86_64                 1/5
  Проверка    : 1:grub2-efi-x64-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.x86_64               2/5
  Проверка    : kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64                            3/5
  Проверка    : 1:grub2-common-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.noarch                4/5
1:grub2-common-2.02-0.64.el7.centos.noarch was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Проверка    : 1:grub2-common-2.02-0.64.el7.centos.noarch                  5/5

Неудача:
  grub2-common.noarch 1:2.02-0.64.el7.centos
  grub2-common.noarch 1:2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2
  grub2-efi-x64.x86_64 1:2.02-0.64.el7.centos
  grub2-efi-x64.x86_64 1:2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2
  kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.5.2.el7

Выполнено!
[user@server123 ~]$
```

С чем это может быть связано и как вообще лечить?

Пробовал `sudo yum clean all` - не помогло. Поиском решения не нашёл, хотя [вижу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36733866/5752652), что не одинок с этой проблемой.

Также видел [упоминания](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56274), что это могли бы быть проблемы с провайдером, но что-то мне сомнительно: у меня в этой подсети порядка десятка серверов обновилось без проблем, а этот ни автоматом, ни руками не хочет обновляться.

Updated Да, формально место в /boot есть:

```
$ df -h
Файловая система        Размер Использовано  Дост Использовано% Cмонтировано в
/dev/mapper/centos-root    50G         3,3G   47G            7% /
devtmpfs                  905M            0  905M            0% /dev
tmpfs                     915M            0  915M            0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     915M          98M  817M           11% /run
tmpfs                     915M            0  915M            0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                 494M         225M  270M           46% /boot
/dev/sda1                 200M         9,8M  191M            5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/centos-home   348G         152G  196G           44% /home
tmpfs                     183M            0  183M            0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                     183M            0  183M            0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                     183M            0  183M            0% /run/user/995
```

, но при попытке открыть появляется ошибка ввода-вывода:

> ls: невозможно получить доступ к boot: Ошибка ввода/вывода

Comment: в разделе /boot мало места. `df -h`

Comment: @KoVadim Ответы - в ответы. )

Comment: даже бы и не подумал бы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пытается распаковать загрузчик нового ядра/ядро и поместить его в /boot. Но федора известна тем, что предлает /boot сделать очень меленьким (пару лет назад было 200мб, чего хватает на два-три ядра).

Подтвердить мысль выполнить `df -h`.

А дальше уже чистить старые ядра и мусор. Или размер бута менять (я так делал, до 1гб увеличил и забыл).